# How to rebuild a group of arrays separated by commas with foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF Pro to get all my `choices` or specific field.  I want to store these choice values into an array structure like this...

```
$mstars = array( 
    'relation' => 'OR',
array (
    'key' => 'product_owner',
    'value' => 'Bob Ross',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
),
array(
    'key' => 'product_owner',
    'value' => 'Michael Jackson',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
),
array(
    'key' => 'product_owner',
    'value' => 'Tom Hanks',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
```

...**Bob, Micheal and Tom are the only things coming from my select choices**.  The 'key' and 'compare' can be manully placed in my loop sense that never changes.  How should I go about building that?  This is what I have so far...

```
//I'm getting the ACF key to find my specific field
$field_key = "field_5b5b34f4ed085";
//I now have field data
$field = get_field_object($field_key);

//initiate an array
$mstars = [];
//loop through all my choices of this specific field
foreach($field['choices'] as $mkey => $mvalue) {
    //how do I add 'key' => 'product_owner', to each sub array?
    //how can I add Bob, Michael and Tom as values to each sub array?
    //how do I add compare => 'LIKE' to each sub array?
}

//I could then use $mstars[] where needed for get_posts() arguments
```

Many thanks on how to do this!

A `var_dump` of my choices looks like this...

```
var_dump($field['choices']);

array(6) { 
  ["Michael Jackson"]=> string(16) "Michael Jackson" 
  ["Bob Ross"]=> string(12) "Bob Ross" 
  ["Tom Hanks"]=> string(13) "Tom Hanks"
}
```

Comment: Please dump `$field['choices']` so I can see what that data looks like.

Comment: You want to add to `$field` or do you want to populate `$mstars` with those values?

Comment: i want to populate $mstars with those values. I want to mimic that original structure I'm showing above.  I updated my post above to show what var_dump of choices looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$mvalue` is a string that contains the name you want:

```
foreach($field['choices'] as $mkey=>$mvalue){
    $mstars[] = array(
     'key'=> 'product_owner',
     'value'=> $mvalue,
     'compare'=> 'LIKE'
    );
}

$mstars['relation'] = 'OR';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this.

```
// Since you always want this, I will add it now as a fixed value.
$mstars = ['relation' => 'OR'];
//loop through all my choices of this specific field
foreach($field['choices'] as $mkey => $mvalue) {
    //how do I add 'key' => 'product_owner', to each sub array?
    //how can I add Bob, Michael and Tom as values to each sub array?
    //how do I add compare => 'LIKE' to each sub array?
    // Make the element you want to add
    $entry = [
        'key' => 'product_owner',
        'value' => $mkey,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ];
    // Add it to the array.
    $mkey[] = $entry;
}
```

One point you might consider. You are storing the 'relation' and the actual choices as siblings. i.e. they are at the same level. You might want to consider a slightly different structure so that you can definitively get to your choice list. Instead of adding the choices directly into $mstars, put them into a known key inside of $mstars.

```
[
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'data' => [
        ['key' => 'product_owner', 'value' => 'Sally', 'compare' => 'LIKE'],
        ['key' => 'product_owner', 'value' => 'Helen', 'compare' => 'LIKE'],
        ['key' => 'product_owner', 'value' => 'Faria', 'compare' => 'LIKE'],
    ]
]
```

Now you can walk through $mstars['data'] and it will *only* contain your data. Just a suggestion.

Also note that `[]` and `array()` are now equivalent in PHP. `[]` is shorter.

Comment: Many thanks! I updated my post so you don't have to guess. the key name is the same as the value name.  either one will work.  I just need either one.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve your expected output by the following:

```
$field = [
    'choices' => [
        'Michael Jackson' => 'Michael Jackson',
        'Bob Ross' => 'Bob Ross',
        'Tom Hanks' => 'Tom Hanks'
    ]
];

$mstars = ['relation' => 'OR'];

foreach ($field['choices'] as $value) {
    $mstars[] = [
        'key' => 'product_owner',
        'value' => $value,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($mstars);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [relation] => OR
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => product_owner
            [value] => Michael Jackson
            [compare] => LIKE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => product_owner
            [value] => Bob Ross
            [compare] => LIKE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => product_owner
            [value] => Tom Hanks
            [compare] => LIKE
        )

)
```